# How to change the radio button color of the SimpleListItemSingleChoice listview in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xaml, android-layout, xamarin.android

Here is my .axml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lv_List2" 
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/></LinerLayout>
```

[image]

I want to change color of the radiobutton.

Activity.CS code

```
 public class SimpleListItemSingleChoiceActivity : Activity
{
    public List<string> _banana = new List<string>();
    ListView _lstView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ListSingleChoice);

        var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar.Title = "List";// action bar title
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        _lstView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lv_List2);

        DataBinding();

        _lstView.ChoiceMode = Android.Widget.ChoiceMode.Single;          
    }

    public void DataBinding()
    {
        ArrayAdapter _adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemSingleChoice, _banana);
        _lstView.Adapter = _adapter;
    }

}
```

_banana is a listview and it contains data, and I am using ArrayAdapter to bind data into list view

Comment: You want to change the color for the selected one only right ?

Comment: @G.hakim Yes...

Comment: I hope you are using appcompat library

Comment: I solved the problem by changing color of the android:colorAccent

Comment: But that will affect the entire application colorAccent anyway goodluck

Comment: Yes you are right , is there any other way?

Comment: well, can you get the reference for the radio button? like do you have a template for your listview? like, show me your adapter code.

Comment: @G.hakim refer to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Resource+Layout.SimpleListItemSingleChoice/)

Answer (score 3):

It's color follows your application theme, so you need go to you `styles.xml`, find this:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

change the `colorAccent` to:

```
<item name="colorAccent">#c42a2a</item>
```

Or other colors.

Comment: where does one finds this `styles.xml` ?